# For the Job application page include the job title of the applicant

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When applying for a job could it be nice that at the top of the page the job title could be included so that when writing the cover letter all the relevant information would show on the page instead of only the company name like this:

[image]

it could display like this:
[image]